# SPDY instead of HTTP2 on Nginx 1.10

Tags: nginx, http2, spdy

I just upgrade a server and decide to install latest stable Nginx version, 1.10.

The problem is that I am getting the error bellow on images and js. I do not get this error on all images, and it is random error.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I try to use spdy on config but I get a warn and test failed.

nginx: [warn] invalid parameter "spdy": ngx_http_spdy_module was superseded by ngx_http_v2_module

Anyway to use SPDY until HTTP2 is more acceptable on Nginx 1.10? Looking for a simple fix that could be done only on Nginx conf.

Comment: Even if you could would it really be worth it now that Chrome has stopped supporting it (http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html?m=1)? SDPY's gone - time to move on. If you e got it already then fair enough to keep it until HTTP/2 is more easily available but if not then don't think it's worth setting up now if you've lived without it until now.

Comment: Maybe I will go back to < 1.9.5 because I use Chrome and I am getting a lot off spdy errors using http2 on Nginx. It is messing with images and js.

Answer (score 0):

I found this patch

https://blog.cloudflare.com/open-sourcing-our-nginx-http-2-spdy-code/

But yesterday I got less spdy errors. And I also had an error on my code when I upgrade server.